Building APK failed in react native expo APP using EAS-CLI
After coding my App and tested on both  expo go app and on adriod emulator and app is working fine on both environment, i decided to build a test apk to install on my physical andriod device so i followed the instruction here Expo APK build-reference
My build wasn't successful as I got errors that are not javascript related error. below is a sample of error I goterror ima

After reading some comment online i decided to take another approach to be able to identify where error is comming from and i run this code npx expo run:android which is makes a development build without using eas, but I got some errors as well and below are error i got
    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'F:\react-app\myapp\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 377

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-av'.
   > SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'F:\react-app\checkstall_import\android\local.properties'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'F:\react-app\myapp\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.       

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

From the error above i noticed a complain about my ANDROID_HOME path which i try to check through and before is my andriod_home path
and since I didn't change the installation directory then the default directory should be what i specified.
After all this i still got error and now i'm stuck as i can't create an apk of my AP please what do i do. what might likely be causing this error?.
